As an international student in the USA, what legal resources are available to help me with housing issues and disputes?
As a fall 2024 international student in the USA, I initially signed a 12-month lease for housing in Rochester, NY. However, upon arriving in Rochester, I discovered that I do not feel safe in the area. Despite expressing my concerns to the landlord and offering to forfeit my deposit, they informed me that they cannot accommodate my request to terminate the lease. I have sent them a formal notice via email, but to my surprise, they continue to charge rent even though I am not residing there.

A local attorney would be a good legal resource.

It is possible that your university has some lower-cost options for providing legal assistance to students.  But it is likely that you'd need to speak with a lawyer to see what your options are or read through the lease you signed and see if there are options for breaking the lease (and presumably paying a penalty)

How exactly "they continue to charge rent"? Just don't pay.

But they can take legal action but I am scared as an international student so please someone can help me with this please! it will be very help me, in this country I feel very lonely. I tried to negotiate with this problem, but they just too rude too me!

Some communities have free legal and mediation help for tenant/landlord disputes.
New York State offers free community dispute resolution services that might be helpful if a tenant and landlord both agree to talk with them.
